# R plot changing Legend's Line's pch color

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have my graph here,

```
plot(c(1:10),type = "l")
lines(c(1:10), type = "p", pch = 20,lwd = 4, col ="#4169E1" )
abline(h = 5,lwd = 2 , col = "#7f41e1")
abline(h = 0,lwd = 2, col = "#41e1b9")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("a", "b", "c"),
       col=c("#7f41e1", "black","#41e1b9"),cex=0.8,lwd=3, lty = c(1, 1, 1), pch = c(NA, 20, NA))
```

[image]

I want to change the color of the b's pch in the legend from black to color seen in the graph "#4169E1".
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: use `pch = 21` and make these changes `legend("bottomright", legend=c("a", "b", "c"), pt.lwd = 0, pt.cex = c(NA, 1.25, NA), pt.bg = c(NA, '#4169E1', NA), col=c("#7f41e1", "black", "#41e1b9"), cex=0.8, lwd=3, lty = c(1, 1, 1), pch = c(NA, 21, NA))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by legending first the lines and after the point like this :

```
plot(c(1:10),type = "l")
lines(c(1:10), type = "p", pch = 20,lwd = 4, col ="#4169E1" )
abline(h = 5,lwd = 2 , col = "#7f41e1")
abline(h = 0,lwd = 2, col = "#41e1b9")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("a", "b", "c"),
       col=c("#7f41e1", "black","#41e1b9"),cex=0.8,lwd=3, lty = c(1, 1, 1), pch = c(NA, NA, NA))

legend("bottomright", legend=c("a", "b", "c"),
       col=c("#7f41e1", "#4169E1","#41e1b9"),cex=0.8,lwd=3,lty=c(0,0,0), pch = c(NA, 20, NA),bty="n")
```

[image]